# What does 'A=B to within 20%' mean? Does this mean |A-B|/B = 20%?

Tags: meaning, mathematics

I am not clear about "within". What is the relationship between A and B?

Answer (score 2):

It means A=B approximately (very approximately), and the error is "within 20%", in other words "*less than or equal* to 20%". The exact expression defining the error is not stated, but 20% is a lot.

It could be, as you speculate, **|A-B|/B** less than or equal **20%**, or it might be **|A-B|/A** less than or equal **20%**.

Either way, they are saying that A and B are roughly equal.